# c# rdlc Set textbox text wihout parameter name string

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Today I use this way to set textbox, by stringParameter

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ParameterName", "Value"));
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

The problem is that don't use autocompletion. So if parametername change, building will not raise anything. Is there a better (safe) way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally is not possible to do it.